# Не поздно ли начинать входить в IT-сферу в таком возрасте?

Tags: java, android, sql, информатика

У меня сложилось нехорошая жизненная ситуация: я не смог отучиться ни на мехмате МГУ из-за слабой нервной системы (математика там совсем другая, нежели геометрия и алгебра в школе, более теоретическая и абстрактная, вообщем, не воспринял ее нормально), ни на физфаке МГУ на очном отделении (не смог понять ядерную физику, которая там проходится без квантов, теормеха, атомки, диффуров, теор.вера.).

В поисках себя хочу попробовать стартануть в IT-сфере. Не сумев себя реализовать в те времена, довел себя дважды посещенной психоневролгии.

Мои начальные условия очень плохи, но они таковы:

- Нет top-tier ВО, нет middle-tier ВО
- Знание английского есть на Upper-medialte level
- В школе была отвратная информатика
- Стою на консультативном учете в районном ПНД, но года 3 там не был
- Сейчас изучаю Java'у по Хорстманну(сейчас на try-catch-finnaly, try с ресурсами), параллельно смотря курс по сетям от Андрея Созыкина. Дошел до сетевого уровня до протокола IP включительно.
- Знаю математику физфака МГУ 3 первых семестров нормально, до сих пор помню
- Непонимание, что нужно изучать еще (Архитектуру ЭВМ и ассемблер, ОСы, алгоритмы и структуры данных, дискретная математика, матан.)
- Вот с помощью плагина meddlemonkey могу качать видео с youtube.com, следовательно, могу качать видео лекций с топ-тиер ВУЗа. На ВМиК МГУ есть предметы по IT, в частности, сложность алгоритмов. Следует ли его изучать?
- Во многих стажировках ради опыта требуется быть студентом тех. ВУЗа.

Обязательно ли заканчивать ВУЗ, чтобы потом работать в IT?

Просьба ко всем отвечающим - говорить честно. Если поздно, то поздно. Нет, значит, нет. Не хочу иметь иллюзий на этот счет. Я человек мнительный и легко поддающийся внешнему влиянию, но иногда смотреть объективно могу, а именно я буду конкурировать с людьми, которые имеют колоссальный опыт в этой сфере. Да и ситуация неимения опыта в 28-29 лет в этой сфере удручает меня (многие пишут, что HR-девки отбитые на всю голову). Следует ли мне пытаться, если в принципе терять мне уже нечего? Вообщем, у меня катастрофа жизненная.
В данное время дошел по Java до многопоточности. SQL не касался.

Comment: Можно. Почему нет? Но нужно ли? Не так тут все медом намазано как говорят. Если есть проблемы с нервами, то на большинстве проектов есть если не вечные (хотя чаще всего вечные), то очень частые нервяки. Вплоть до того, что ты не в 3 ночи не можешь заснуть и лезешь на прод проверять - не поломал ли твой комит там что-то. Я себе невроз и бессоницу так заработал.

Comment: Зависит от того куда попадешь. Точнее если правильно сказать, что выберешь. Первая работа она пофиг какая. Через год если в тебе есть уверенность и желание учиться и развиваться открыты почти все двери. И ты можешь выбрать то место где тебе реально хорошо, без нервоза и бессониц

Comment: Я, естественно, не мечу в Google. Но надо делать все поэтапно. начать с маленькой компании.

Comment: Мне кажется лет до 65 такие вопросы задавать себе не стоит) Это вопрос не возраста, а мотивации. Ничего не бойтесь! Воспринимайте мелкие неудачи как жизненные уроки. Удачи вам! :)

Comment: Не сказал бы, что дважды вылетев и трижды полежав в психоневролгии, это мелкие поражения. Это огромные катастрофы.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Нет не поздно.**

- У меня есть друг который в 31 решил, что ему надоело продавать пиццу. Ему понадобилось чуть больше года чтоб найти первую работу. Сейчас ему 35 и он работает в очень крутой компании и получает приглашения на собесы в Facebook и Booking.
- В 27 лет я лично собирал тенты на машины. Спустя полтора года я получил свой первый офер. Сейчас я работаю в Тинькофф.
- Я видел человека который бросил работу в 26 и за 8 месяцев получил свой первый офер в Сбербанк

К чему все это? К тому, что **никогда не поздно**. Тяжело? Да конечно. Придется перечитать огромный пак литературы. Перерыть пол интернета и написать гору говнокода на который спустя год смотреть будет стремно. В начале будет реально тяжело, потом проще.

Круто если вы сможете найти себе ментора. Ментор сможет вас направить, что учить действительно важно, а что можно отложить на потом, т.к. на старте не поймешь за что браться, а как начинаешь читать гайды начинаешь еще больше не понимать. Можно взять курс, но там нужно понимать, что первая задача любого курса: "Взять с вас деньги" и они зачастую растянуты. Я сам видел как парнишка на курсе учил как дурак до самых низов SQLite который в Android используется вообще поверхностно. Ну и ментор этот тот человек который скажет: "Бро, ты делаешь говнище, поправь. Вот так и вот так".

Ну и потом реально сложный этап - это этап собесов. Вам будут все говорить "Нет", и тут главное не забить (мне понадобилось примерно 25-30 собесов, чтоб получить свой первый офер). Но на них ходить нужно, вот [моя статейка](https://habr.com/ru/post/471840/) на эту тему.

**По поводу знаний?**
Для старта вам хватит понимание, что такое переменная и каких-то самых азов математики. Да в будущем вам понадобится и алгоритмика, но это не то, что ***must have*** для первого офера.

- Английский для работы в России так же не обязателен. Да конечно документация и все лучшие и главное актуальные материалы на английском. Но никто не отменял Google переводчик, конечно с ним труднее, но это решит проблему отсутствия языка. Потом как уже будете уверенно чувствовать себя на работе, займетесь английским. К слову я начинал с минимальными знаниями, сейчас читаю книги на английском и спокойно учу язык.
- **Курсы?** Да в основном они все для студентов. Но есть и исключения. Например Сбербанк минимум 2 раза в год запускает для всех. Тинькофф так же вроде бы не ограничивает только студентами. Но надо понимать, что эти курсы бесплатны не просто так. Компании ищут себе таланты и будет предварительный собес и на курс попадут только те которые знают хорошо и в которых есть потенциал.

Главное найти первую работу. Тут пофигу что это будет, любой оффер подойдет. Через год, при условии того что вы уверены в себе (очень круто прокачивает этот скилл собеседования даже если не планируете менять работу, просто для прокачки см. статью=)) и этот год реально занимались своим развитием вам открыты почти все двери. На моем опыте я скажу: Я принял первый офер. Отработал год, а потом задался целью, что пойду только в крутую IT компанию. И начал ходить целенаправленно на собеседования ТОЛЬКО и ТОЛЬКО в компании уровня: Mail, Kaspersky, Sberbank и т.д.

Так что, **все возможно**. И есть много крутых компаний которые в первую очередь посмотрят на ваши навыки и потенциал, а только потом на ваш возраст.

P.S. А еще если вы в Москве или в другом большом городе. Ищите все митапы на вашу тему. Вы по началу там понимать ничего не будете, но оно все же откладывается. К тому же это место где можно обзавестись полезными знакомствами (я вот так себе студента нашел). Плюс вы будете в курсе всех мероприятий в вашем городе. Например я в свое время так попал в [Android Academy MSK](https://habr.com/ru/company/avito/blog/445586/). Важно понимать что IT это огромная тусовка. Крутые ребята всегда хотят и готовы делиться опытом. И тут важно знать друг друга. Потому что не редко бывают ситуации вроде такой:

- Вань, нам тут над бы разраба, можно даж джуна.
- Слушай, вчера был на митапе, там парнишка задавал вопросы толковые, потом пообщались в кулуарах, вообще с виду толковый парень. Давай я ему в телеге напишу.

Comment: А вот насчет ВУЗа что Вы можете сказать? Я сейчас смотрю курс по компьютерным сетям Андрея Созыкина - очень интересно рассказывает. hh.ru говорит, что чтобы устроиться на стажировку, нужно быть студентом тех. ВУЗа.

Comment: В Тинькофф я не попаду уже. Там до 25 лет.

Comment: Мне 31, я в Тинькоффе. И попал я туда не в 25, а в 30. Еще есть вопросы?

Comment: Никому ваш вуз не интересен. Вы либо знаете либо нет. Важно понимать, что никому не нужны ваши бумажки об образовании. Людям важно чтоб вы решали проблемы. Если вы можете решать проблемы - вы полезен, если нет то хоть у вас будет Гарвард и Оксфорд вы никому не нужны. Этот ответ на 1ый вопрос

Comment: Ну, тогда у меня еще есть время.

Comment: Сергей, я имел в виду стажировку.

Comment: Ну стажировки в основном да. Сейчас точно не скажу, но вроде как руководитель разработки говорил, что нет ограничений по возрасту. Сбер точно не парится по этому поводу. Сам лично проходил

Comment: Но есть другая проблема, а именно то, что в ПНД на консультативном учете стою.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109407/discussion-between-sergei-buvaka-and--).